# How to search all friend request sent in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with `join` in SQL. I have 2 tables:

1. tbl_register
2. request

There is a problem: it returns only `NULL` in `req_from_id`.

`tbl_register` table:

```
UserID     f_name      Designationnm    Comapny_name
1      aaa                 CEO              Apple
2      Rajeev      General manager          Dell
3      upendra     Managing director        Dell
4      soumendr        Vice president      lenovo
9      Suneal     Managing director        Apple
8       asa                CEO             Apple
```

`request` table:

```
req_from_id req_to_id   req_status
2              9               0
3              9               0
4              9               0
2              8               0
2              1               0
```

I need to get output like this:

```
f_name       Designationnm   Comapny_name  UserID    req_from_id
aaa  aa             CEO            Apple     1             2
Rajeev          General manager    Dell      2             9
Suneal          Managing director  Apple     9             2
asa               CEO              Apple     8             2
```

What I have tried:

```
select distinct 
tb1.UserID,tb1.f_name,tb1.Designationnm,tb1.Comapny_name,tb2.req_from_id      
from Tbl_register tb1 
left join
tbl_friend_and_match_request tb2
on 
tb1.UserID = tb2.req_from_id
where 
Comapny_name like '%a%' or Designationnm like '%Manager%'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select   
tb1.UserID,tb1.f_name,tb1.Designationnm,tb1.Comapny_name,tb2.req_from_id      
from Tbl_register tb1 
left join
tbl_friend_and_match_request tb2
on tb2.req_to_id = tb1.userid
where company_name in ('Apple') or DesignationName in ('General manager')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl_register.f_name, 
  tbl_register.Designationnm, 
  tbl_register.Comapny_name, 
  tbl_registerUserID, 
  request.req_from_id 
FROM tbl_register
INNER JOIN request ON tbl_register.UserID=request.req_to_id  
GROUP BY tbl_register.UserID;
```

Comment: Column 'tbl_register.f_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.